# ios: mapkit how to enable curent location button on map?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, mapkit

I am developing application which is showing map. I enabled User current location in map properties and its now showing **Blue** dot indicating user's current location but now I want to enable Button in Bottom Left of below Pic  (Snap shot of Maps application in iPhone).

Please tell me that how do I get this on Map

[image]

Comment: MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem is what you need. try searching on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find the implementation of this

[iOS6MapsUserHeadingButton](https://github.com/jcalonso/iOS6MapsUserHeadingButton)

Following is the code and you can find the images in the above given link

```
//User Heading Button states images
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyButtonHighlight.png"];
UIImage *buttonImageHighlight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyButton.png"];
UIImage *buttonArrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LocationGrey.png"];

//Configure the button
userHeadingBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[userHeadingBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(startShowingUserHeading:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//Add state images
[userHeadingBtn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[userHeadingBtn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[userHeadingBtn setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[userHeadingBtn setImage:buttonArrow forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Button shadow
userHeadingBtn.frame = CGRectMake(5,425,39,30);
userHeadingBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
userHeadingBtn.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
userHeadingBtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
userHeadingBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
userHeadingBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
userHeadingBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.0f);

[self.mapView addSubview:userHeadingBtn];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:mapView];   
[trackButton setTarget:self];
[trackButton setAction:@selector(track:)];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:trackButton, nil] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem and pass it to the MKMapview wherever you defined the mapview. Something like below :

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.map];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
}
```